# Select ASP.NET treeView

Tags: asp.net, treeview, controls

I have only one question :
I have ASP.NET TreeView control. Each node in the TreeView has a Tag property assigned. All i Want to do is to catch the NodeClicked event in JavaScript and display the TagProperty in the textbox . Is this possible ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can add call to javascript function inside, treeview SelectedNodeChanged event handler.
For instance :

```
protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
  // Do whatever you're doing
  Node.Attributes.Add("OnClick","javaScriptName()");
}
```

Maybe, it's more easy to use the behind code (inside the event above) to change the textbox value.

Comment: reference : http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/202.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107150/asp-net-treeview-and-selecting-the-selected-node