# Getting the SelectedIndex of a child node in a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, selectedindex

I am currently working on a wpf project in C#.

I have a treeview created that has parent nodes with childen nodes inside of it.

I was wondering if there was a way to get the index of the child node the user clicked on. (Simmilar to  ".SelectedIndex"  when using comboboxes)

I have tried Various ways such as:

```
int val =TreeView.SelectedItemProperty.GlobalIndex;
```

and

```
fileInput.IndexOf(treeView1.SelectedItem);
```

But they dont seem to work.

Any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It is a tree, a core data structure in software engineering.  Nodes in a tree don't have an index, it is not an array.  Try to visualize the branches on a real tree.  You can only get to the leaf by hopping from one branch to another, several times.

Comment: ahh that kinda makes sense. Im trying to work with microprocessors code that he suggested but using .Nodes doesnt seem to be an option and im not sure how to create the event: TreeViewEventArgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may you have to loop over tree nodes to get the index of `SelectedItem`. you can do that using `OnItemSelected` event.for ex.

```
Int32 selectedNodeIndex=-1;
private void TreeView1_OnItemSelected(Object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      Int32 index=0;
      foreach(var _item in TreeView1.Items)
      {
         if(_item==TreeView1.SelectedItem)
         {
                selectedNodeIndex = index;
                break;
         }
          index++;
      }    
}
```

Comment: How do I create TreeViewEventArgs e and does this go inside of my treeView1_SelectedItemChange Event?

Comment: also i get an error when i do the treeView.Nodes (it doesnt like the .Nodes part)

Comment: for the event i get the error "The type or namespace name 'TreeViewEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: For the "Nodes" error it says "TreeView does not contain a definitoin for 'Nodes' and no extension method 'Nodes' accepting a first argument type of 'SystemWindowsControls.TreeView' could be found"

Comment: and I agree with Hans Passant's comment. I just want to help you to do what you want.

Comment: Im marking you as the answer .. only problem I had with your answer is that there is no onItemSelected event in wpf (unless u renamed the event)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107150/asp-net-treeview-and-selecting-the-selected-node) discusses exactly what you need I think. About handling the `SelectedNodeChanged` event and also a custom piece of code for an event that fires when the currently selected node is clicked...because then the `SelectedNodeChanged` doesn't fire (the selected node doesn't change actually). Good luck!